# Finding the same value in the list<Object>?

Tags: java

Here i will get many CustomizableMenus objects in the list, so i want to find if any two CustomizableMenus objects contains same cust.getComponentState();
then i want to find that getComponentState(); here i am posting my code.How can i get the value from the list.

```
for(CustomizableMenus cust : ra.getAction().getCustomizablemenu()){

    cust.getComponentId();
    cust.getComponentIdentification();
    cust.getComponentName();
    cust.getComponentState();

    custList.add(cust);

    System.out.println("cust menus in ctrl custid "+ cust.getComponentId()+"component name is "+cust.getComponentName()+"identification "+cust.getComponentIdentification());

}
```

Comment: Within for loop, iterate the list one more time and compare with each value of out loop with inner loop, this will give you the match of the list elements.

Comment: @GoXR3Plus  explained

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare `n` items with `n` items so you will run a loop with complexity `O(n^2)` plus the complexity of if statements:

Whatever you are using `Array`,`List`,`Map`,.. the logic is the same.

---

General Code:

```
 for(Item item1:yourList.getItems()){
   for(Item item2:yourList.getItems())
      if(item2!=item1) //not compare the item with it's self
        //if they have the same component state
        if(item2.getComponentState() == item1.getComponentState()){
          //..do something
        }
      }
```

---

About your situation:

```
   for(CustomizableMenus cust1 : ra.getAction().getCustomizablemenu()){
    for(CustomizableMenus cust2 : ra.getAction().getCustomizablemenu()){
      if(cust1 != cust2 ) //not compare the item with it's self
        //if they have the same component state
        if(cust1 .getComponentState() == cust2 .getComponentState()){
          //..do something
        }
      }
```

---

**Edit:**

> Why i need to use `if(cust1 != cust2 )`

You have to loops here.Let's see two examples:

Entering the loop for the first time you are getting the first item of the List,so `cust1`(is now the first element of the list).Now we are entering the second loop and you are getting the first item of the List again.So now `cust1` and `cust2` are the same(the first item of the list).We don't want to compare them `(cust1 .getComponentState() == cust2 .getComponentState())` cause they are the same item.

The second loop continues with comparing `cust1`(which is still the first item of the List) with the `cust2` which now is the second item of the List.And so on...

When the second loop exits,then the `cust1` is becoming the second item of the List,after that we are entering the second loop.First we compare `cust1`(which now is the second item of the list) with the `cust2`(which now is the first item of the List) . Then we compare  `cust1` with `cust2`(which now happens to be the second item of the List,but also `cust1` is the second item of the List,so we don't need to compare them for `(cust1 .getComponentState() == cust2 .getComponentState())` cause it is the same item.

I hope you understand why i am using `if(cust1 != cust2 )`

---

**Finally:**

This solution is only for academic purposes.
**Check the link below for better solutions in term of performance.**

http://javarevisited.blogspot.gr/2015/06/3-ways-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-java.html

Comment: cust1 and cust2 will be always same beacause after the cust1 next cust 2 will be excecuted so obviously we will get the same object's. so it will never be not equal righ!!!?

Comment: @Mike As you describe it no , but i added it in case you @override `equals` method ;)

Comment: Even the controller is not entering to the if condition also because firist and second objects are same. Dont mine i am not experienced. if i remove not equal operation and kept double equal operation it is entering.

Comment: @Mike I was a little bit wrong before.Look Mike you need the if not equals because when you start the loop for example with the first element then the second loop will start with the first element.You dont want to equal yourself with yourself.I will add more info soon.:)

Comment: @Mike Edited the question with briefly explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for a *lookup* mechanism. On every iteration you might want to store that object in a map. The map could have the component state as key and the object as value something on the lines of

```
Map<String, CustomizableMenus> map = new HashMap<>();
```

To add entry to the map

```
map.put(cust.getComponentState(), cust);
```

and then you just lookup the map using

`map.get(cust.getComponentState())`

Offcourse, you could just loop through the list again for the object (which might be a problem if the list size is huge)

Comment: if i print that map.get(cust.getComponentState()) is printing class name

Comment: CustomizableMenus c = map.get(cust.getComponentState()); Then, c.getComponentId() or whatever.  By default, when you print object, it calls the toString() method.